# pySpark count IDs on condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following dataset and working with **PySpark**

```
df = sparkSession.createDataFrame([(5, 'Samsung', '2018-02-23'),
                                   (8, 'Apple', '2018-02-22'),
                                   (5, 'Sony', '2018-02-21'),
                                   (5, 'Samsung', '2018-02-20'),
                                   (8, 'LG', '2018-02-20')],
                                   ['ID', 'Product', 'Date']
                                  )

+---+-------+----------+
| ID|Product|      Date|
+---+-------+----------+
|  5|Samsung|2018-02-23|
|  8|  Apple|2018-02-22|
|  5|   Sony|2018-02-21|
|  5|Samsung|2018-02-20|
|  8|     LG|2018-02-20|
+---+-------+----------+
# Each ID will appear ALWAYS at least 2 times (do not consider the case of unique IDs in this df)
```

Each ID should increment the PRODUCT counter only when it represents the higher frequency.
In case of equal frequency, the most recent date should decide which product receives +1.

From the sample above, the desired output would be:

```
+-------+-------+
|Product|Counter|
+-------+-------+
|Samsung|      1|
|  Apple|      1|
|   Sony|      0|
|     LG|      0|
+-------+-------+


# Samsung - 1 (preferred twice by ID=5)
# Apple - 1 (preferred by ID=8 more recently than LG)
# Sony - 0 (because ID=5 preferred Samsung 2 time, and Sony only 1) 
# LG - 0 (because ID=8 preferred Apple more recently)
```

What is the most efficient way with PySpark to achieve this result?

Comment: What should be the output if the product is recent and preferred only once. Another scenario where the the product is preferred multiple times but less recent?

Comment: Samsung is 1 because an ID can assign +1 only to one product, which is the one who has been associated with the highest frequency (or in case of equal frequency, most recent date)

Comment: If a given ID has only one record it doesn't have to be consider. Here I am dealing only with IDs that are NOT unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to pick the most frequent product for each `ID`, breaking ties using the 
most recent `Date`

So first, we can get the count for each product/ID pair using:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = df.select(
    'ID',
    'Product',
    'Date', 
    f.count('Product').over(Window.partitionBy('ID', 'Product')).alias('count')
)
df.show()
#+---+-------+----------+-----+
#| ID|Product|      Date|count|
#+---+-------+----------+-----+
#|  5|   Sony|2018-02-21|    1|
#|  8|     LG|2018-02-20|    1|
#|  8|  Apple|2018-02-22|    1|
#|  5|Samsung|2018-02-23|    2|
#|  5|Samsung|2018-02-20|    2|
#+---+-------+----------+-----+
```

Now you can use a `Window` to rank each product for each ID. We can use `pyspark.sql.functions.desc()` to sort by `count` and `Date` descending. If the `row_number()` is equal to 1, that means that row is first.

```python
w = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy(f.desc('count'), f.desc('Date'))
df = df.select(
    'Product',
    (f.row_number().over(w) == 1).cast("int").alias('Counter')
)
df.show()
#+-------+-------+
#|Product|Counter|
#+-------+-------+
#|Samsung|      1|
#|Samsung|      0|
#|   Sony|      0|
#|  Apple|      1|
#|     LG|      0|
#+-------+-------+
```

Finally `groupBy()` the Product and pick the value for maximum value for `Counter`:

```python
df.groupBy('Product').agg(f.max('Counter').alias('Counter')).show()
#+-------+-------+
#|Product|Counter|
#+-------+-------+
#|   Sony|      0|
#|Samsung|      1|
#|     LG|      0|
#|  Apple|      1|
#+-------+-------+
```

---

**Update**

Here's a little bit of a simpler way:

```python
w = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy(f.desc('count'), f.desc('Date'))
df.groupBy('ID', 'Product')\
    .agg(f.max('Date').alias('Date'), f.count('Product').alias('Count'))\
    .select('Product', (f.row_number().over(w) == 1).cast("int").alias('Counter'))\
    .show()
#+-------+-------+
#|Product|Counter|
#+-------+-------+
#|Samsung|      1|
#|   Sony|      0|
#|  Apple|      1|
#|     LG|      0|
#+-------+-------+
```

Comment: In this way the counter is always 1. I want that each unique id increments the counter of a product when the conditions are met

Comment: I guess it can be fixed just changing max() to sum()

Comment: @Alex could you please [edit] your question and show an example where it makes a difference.